# Image is not saved/updated into database using Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, api

I am trying to save my image into database while creating my user and i am using postman for this

My Code:

```
public function register(Request $request) {

    $body = $request->all();

    $userProfile = $body['user_profile'];
    $userPrev = $body['privileges'];
    $userProfile['is_super_admin'] = $userPrev['is_super_admin'];
    $facilities = $userPrev['facilities'];

    $bodyObj = array_merge($userProfile, $userPrev);

    $validator = UserValidations::validateUser($bodyObj);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response([
            'status' => false,
            'message'   => __('messages.validation_errors'),
            'errors' => $validator->errors()->all()
        ], 200);
    }

    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {

        If (Input::hasFile('image')) {

            $file = Input::file('image');

            $destinationPath = public_path() . '/profile_images/';
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

            $this->user->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['profile_pic' => $filename]);
        }
```

My user is created and saved into database, but the image is not.
Your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am really confused. You want to store image in database (bad Idea). Secondly, You want to store image in database but you are storing the file name only.

Suggetion : If you would like to store images in database you have an option to convert it into base64 and store the string. While retrieving you could decode base64. For example:

```
$file = Input::file('image');    
$img_data = file_get_contents($file);
$base64 = $base64_encode($img_data);
$this->user->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['profile_pic' => $base64 ]);
```

Another suggetion [Best way] : store path in the database and store the file in the storage or public and use the url to access the image

However if you still want to save it on database

```
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents(Input::file('image')));
$this->user->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['profile_pic' => $image ]);
```